# Excel Vba function stops working on reopen

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I was trying to set a vba function that changes the color of a hyperlink when it links to a non existing file. For that, I got the following code on a standard module.

```
Function FileExist(path As String) As Boolean
    If Dir(path) <> vbNullString Then FileExist = True
End Function
```

Then I used said function as a conditional formatting for the cells I wanted and it worked as intended.I then saved the file as a macro enabled workbook  and closed the program.

When i reopened it, it stopped working. the function was returning false for every imput. The only way i got it to work again was by going to "save as" and saving it again as macro enabled and then refreshing the whole thing .

I verified the trust center and even set to "enable all macros", still it would not work after i reopened the file unless I did the procedure  mentioned before.

I have no idea what could be the problem, so i'd appreciate any help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where does the macro reside? PERSONNAL.XLSB?

Answer (score 0):

kinda solved it. The problem was that i was verifying local paths with the function. When i opened the file, it didn't manage to find the local path. When i saved it, tho, it was able to recover the file directory and the function started to work again. When i set a remote path, it worked full time.

thanks for the attention